# Google Maps Places API - how to get name of a place?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

When I change pointer on the map, I want to get name of a place.
I'm able to get lat and lng of a place on the map, but I want to get name of that place. For exampl lat: 43.669992353311635, lng: -79.4108552  is TORONTO. What is mistake in my code?

library: react-google-maps

```
  onDragEnd: ({ setDrag, setCenter, setUseMyLocation, onChangeMapCoords  }) => () => {
    const center = refs.map.getCenter();
    const placeName = refs.map.getPlaces();
    console.log("ACTION sp8 map center", placeName)
    // console.log("ACTION sp8 map center", { lat: center.lat(), lng: center.lng()})

    setUseMyLocation(false);
    setDrag(false);
    setCenter(({ lat: center.lat(), lng: center.lng() }));
    resetSearchBox();
  },
```

Comment: please use 3 backticks code block for code section.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is it possible to get an address from coordinates using google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008949/is-it-possible-to-get-an-address-from-coordinates-using-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
 val geocoder = Geocoder(requireContext(), Locale.getDefault())
  // parameter 1 is the number of results you want, a maximum of 5
 val addresses: List<Address> = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) to reverse geocode the latLng you are getting onDragEnd. This way, you can get the name of the address from the reverse geocoding.

Here is a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/directions-iw3olc?file=Map.js) and the code snippet of Geocoding services below:

```
  onDragEnd(e) {
    console.log(e.latLng);
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    let loc = e.latLng;
    geocoder.geocode({ location: loc }, (results, status) => {
      if (status === "OK") {
        if (results[0]) {
          console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
          window.alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        window.alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```